# Help in creating script

Tags: linux, shell-script, logs, gzip

I am currently working on script with the following goals:

1. Script will check every 15-minute if there is `AppA.log4` in `/logs` directory. There are numerous apps in `/logs` directory, for example `AppA.log4`, `AppB.log4`, `AppC.log4`
2. If there is `AppA.log4`, it will be renamed to `AppA.log.<timestamp>`
3. `zip` the renamed file and move to `/backupDIR`

So far, I have created working script however it is hardcoded.

Can you help improving this to be more dynamic? For example, `AppA.log4` and `AppB.log4`  will be moved and zipped, leaving `AppC.log4` in the `/logs` directory.

What if there's a separate file that lists all the App (`AppA` and `AppB`) that will be read by this script. How can I apply it here. Thank you in advance.

```
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M"`
LOGS="AppA.log.4"
APPLOGS_DIR="/logs/"
BACKUP_DIR="/backupDIR/"

cd $APPLOGS_DIR;

if [ -f "$LOGS" ];
then
        mv $LOGS $BACKUP_DIR;
                cd $BACKUP_DIR;
                mv $LOGS AppA_$TIMESTAMP;
        gzip AppA_$TIMESTAMP;
else
    echo "No log file to be backed up"
fi
```

Comment: use ```ls | find *.log4 | sed s/log4/log``` to dynamically use the names (also it will rename log4 to log)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Greatly appreciated.

What I mean is, my goal now is to move and gzip AppA.log4 and AppB.log4. However there is still AppC.log4 in the /logs/ directory. I just want to specify AppA and AppB. I am thinking of another file where I can input AppA and AppB. The script will read this, but not yet sure on how can I implement it.

Comment: I think I understand what you want to do, but please edit your post to show the content of your `/logs` directory _before_ and the desired content _after_ running your script, so that we can understand which files should be treated in what way.

Comment: @UnixDummy001 Can you please elaborate more about making it dynamic? I mean do you want to skip specific files or want to archive specific files?

Comment: @theSwapnilSaste Please note that parsing the output of `ls` is [highly disrecommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) as it will stumble on spaces or other special characters in the filenames (even though it would appear that in this case, the names are "well-behaved" in that respect). Also, why do you pipe the output of `ls` into `find`?

Comment: @theSwapnilSaste it's absolutely pointless piping `ls` into `find`, because `find` doesn't care about its _stdin_. What you've written is equivalent to `find *.log4 | sed s/log4/log`, which will also fail because the `sed` is missing a trailing `/`

Comment: You say you want the files zipped, but you're using `gzip`. On UNIX/Linux platforms `gzip` is definitely the preferred solution, but it doesn't zip as in `ZIP.EXE` on Windows, it compresses.

Comment: Are you writing for `sh` or for `bash`?

Comment: Have you considered that the source log file(s) might be in use? (Something is still writing to them.) In which case once you have compressed them you could end up losing log data that's being written to the now-deleted log file.

Comment: @roaima, hello. that is why I am only moving the .log4 file. The app is writing to the .log file until it reached certain filesize, for example 20MB. Then it will be moved to .log1, and so on. As long as the script will run before a new .log4 is overwritten, this should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `for` loop and use *string manipulation* to generate output file name `${var%.*}` based on input file name

```
TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M")
APPLOGS_DIR="./logs"
BACKUP_DIR="./backupDIR"

# canonicalize relative paths
APPLOGS_DIR=$(realpath "$APPLOGS_DIR")
BACKUP_DIR=$(realpath "$BACKUP_DIR")

# delete this line - just for demo
echo "AppA.log.4\nAppB.log.4" >> ./index.txt

# read file names from list
LOGS=$(sort ./index.txt | uniq) || exit 127

cd "$APPLOGS_DIR" || exit 127

for log in $LOGS
  do
    if [ -f "$log" ]
      then
        mv -f $log "$BACKUP_DIR"
        cd "$BACKUP_DIR" || exit 127
        mv $log ${log%.*}_${TIMESTAMP}
        gzip ${log%.*}_${TIMESTAMP}
        cd "$APPLOGS_DIR"
      else
        echo "No log file to be backed up"
    fi
done
```

However, just archive & remove file can be done without `cd`

```
while IFS='' read -r log || [ "$log" ]
  do
    [ -f "$APPLOGS_DIR/$log" ] && \
    gzip -nc "$APPLOGS_DIR/$log" > "$BACKUP_DIR/${log%.*}_${TIMESTAMP}.${log##*.}.gz" && \
    rm "$APPLOGS_DIR/$log" || \
    echo "No '$log' file to be backed up"
done <<< $(sort ./index.txt | uniq)
```

or as one-liner (when output file names doesn't matter and file names does not contain whitespaces) use the `-S` flag for suffix and process the *index.txt* straight from `gzip` without any loop

```
cd "$APPLOGS_DIR" && \
gzip -S .${TIMESTAMP}.gz $(cat $OLDPWD/index.txt) && \
mv -f *.${TIMESTAMP}.gz "$BACKUP_DIR"
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified what you provided to add a for loop where you can specify the various log prefixes.  This assumes you are calling this script every 15 minutes from a job scheduler such as cron or autosys, if not then it can be wrapped in a while true loop with a 15 minute sleep.

```
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M"`
LOGS="AppA AppB"
# to pull log prefixes from a file replace with the next line
#LOGS="$(cat prefixes.txt)"
LOGSUFFIX=".log.4"
APPLOGS_DIR="/logs"
BACKUP_DIR="/backupDIR"

for LOG in ${LOGS}
do
    if [ -f "${APPLOGS_DIR}/${LOG}${LOGSUFFIX}" ]
    then
        mv "${APPLOGS_DIR}/${LOG}${LOGSUFFIX}" "${BACKUP_DIR}/${LOG}_${TIMESTAMP}"
        gzip "${BACKUP_DIR}/${LOG}_${TIMESTAMP}"
    else
        echo "No ${LOG}${LOGSUFFIX} file to be backed up"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Is this an answer? It has Syntax errors, unquoted file paths and you give no explanation whatsoever. And also it does not help with OPs request to "help improving this to be more dynamic".

Comment: upvoted because syntax error was just a missing quote and unquoted paths are no problem as long as not containing whitespaces